# Can Someone tell me where I went wrong in this proof

Tags: solution-verification, summation, binomial-coefficients, problem-solving

The question asked to find the solution to $ \sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1)\binom{n}{k}$. Here's what I did:
By the binomial theorem, we know that $ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k = (1+x)^n$.
Set $x=x_1^2$. Then $ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(x_1^2)^k = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x_1^{2k} =  (1+x_1^2)^n$. If you multiply by $x_1$ and differentiate with respect to $x_1$, you get $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x_1^{2k+1} =  x_1(1+x_1^2)^n \implies \sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1)\binom{n}{k}x_1^{2k} = (1+x_1^2)^n + 2nx_1^2(1+x_1^2)^{n-1}$

So, $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1)\binom{n}{k} = 2^n + n2^{n} = 2^n(n+1)$ when $x_1=1$.

Whenever I test this by typing it into a calculator, it's always off by one, so I think the actual solution is $2^n(n+1)-1$, but I am not sure where I messed up. I would appreciate feedback.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom nkx^k=(1+x)^n-1$, not $(1+x)^n$.

Comment: wow thank you so much, I guess there was a typo in my book

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Can Someone tell me where I went wrong in this proof" says nothing about the subject of the question. It's a useless title.

Comment: This forum has rules and guidelines for posting. I suggest you try to follow them to get better feedback in this site.

Comment: @jjagmath, I appreciate your concern, and I will keep this in mind for the future, but I got a response fairly quickly, and I think there was enough information in my post for him to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an alternative approach that avoids derivatives:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n (2k+1)\binom{n}{k}
&= 2\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \\
&= 2\sum_{k=1}^n n\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \\
&= 2n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \\
&= 2n\cdot 2^{n-1} + (2^n-1) \\
&= (n+1)2^n-1
\end{align}

Comment: thanks for showing me this alternative approach! It's interesting seeing the different ways you can approach a problem like this